# kineticjs mouse event does not listen when I use an array

Tags: javascript, html, kineticjs

In kintic JS of HTML5 I am trying to vanish lines on mouse over it works fine when I am doing it with variables:
http://jsfiddle.net/Vbwta/

```
        var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
        lines0= new Kinetic.Line({
        points: [73+10, 70+10, 340+10, 23+10],
        stroke: 'red',
        strokeWidth: 7,
      });

      lines0.on('mouseover', function() {
            lines0.hide();
          layer.draw();;            
         });

    lines1= new Kinetic.Line({
        points: [53, 50, 320, 03],
        stroke: 'red',
        strokeWidth: 7,
      });

      lines1.on('mouseover', function() {
            //document.body.style.cursor = 'pointer';
            lines1.hide();
          layer.draw();;            
         });
```

But the same thing does not work properly when I am using array:
http://jsfiddle.net/uNak5/

```
var lines= new Array();
    lines[0]= new Kinetic.Line({
        points: [73+10, 70+10, 340+10, 23+10],
        stroke: 'red',
        strokeWidth: 7,
      });

      lines[0].on('mouseover', function() {
            lines[a].hide();
          layer.draw();;            
         });

    lines[1]= new Kinetic.Line({
        points: [53, 50, 320, 03],
        stroke: 'red',
        strokeWidth: 7,
      });

      lines[1].on('mouseover', function() {
            //document.body.style.cursor = 'pointer';
            lines[1].hide();
          layer.draw();;            
         });


         layer.add(lines[0]);
         layer.add(lines[1]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/uNak5/1/

I updated the code, you had the reference to your array item set to

```
    lines[a]
```

rather that

```
    lines[0]
```

in your listener

```
    .on('mouseover', function());
```

Comment: Or, simply use `this.hide()`

Comment: I agree with Shmiddty, (this) can be used in your .on() to refer to the item itself. Example, with some extra fun.